# How do I count rows and columns of this data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have installed a package `covdata` which is a data package for R using this command `remotes::install_github("kjhealy/covdata")`

Now, I need to know how do I display this data so that I can count rows and columns OR what commands do I use to get the number of rows and columns?

Comment: `?dim` for the data dimensions. https://github.com/kjhealy/covdata givers instruction in loading the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your data is in a dataframe or matrix `nrow(data)` will give your row numbers and `ncol(data)` will give you column numbers. `dim(data)` will give you rows and columns. If your data is in a vector then `length(data)` will give its length.

Comment: library(covdata) this did the job, and covnat displayed in a list.